# If I allocate memory in one thread in C++ can I de-allocate it in another

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, heap-memory

If I allocate memory in one thread in C++ (either new or malloc) can I de-allocate it in another, or must both occur in the same thread?  Ideally, I'd like to avoid this in the first place, but I'm curious to know is it legal, illegal or implementation dependent.

**Edit:**  The compilers I'm currently using include VS2003, VS2008 and Embedded C++ 4.0, targetting XP, Vista, Windows 7 and various flavours of Windows CE / PocketPC & Mobile.  So basically all Microsoft but across an array of esoteric platforms.

Comment: Threads are not spoken about at all in the C++ standard. It's all implementation specific.

Comment: if you tell use witch compiler, os etc you are using you may get some more helpful answsers

Comment: @Ian, compiler & OS details added.

Comment: Foe efficient inter-thread comms of large data items, there is little alternative except the more complex pooling of inter-thread comms objects in thread-safe containers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally, malloc/new/free/delete on multi threaded systems are thread safe, so this should be no problem - and allocating in one thread , deallocating in another is a quite common thing to do.

As threads are an implementation feature, it certainly is implementation dependant though - e.g. some systems require you to link with a multi threaded runtime library.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing about new/delete themselves that prevent you from allocating and deallocating in separate threads.  As many have said, the Standard is silent on multi-threading -- there is neither support for multi-threading, nor is there anything preventing you from doing it using any of the standard facilities.  This is both good and bad in that you can do anything you want, but the language provides no direct mechanism to help you do it safely.

There are many potential technical issues you may need to contend with however.  Many compilers have multi-threaded- and single-threaded flavors of the runtime libraries that implement new & delete, so you must be sure you use the right one.  (VS 2008 has done away with the single-threaded CRT, so this is not an issue there.)  More importantly, your software must be designed from the ground up to be multi-thread aware, and this is the biggest challenge for us.  Resources need to be protected, ownership must be clear, and you need to avoid deadlocks & race conditions.  But while this is probably the most important and difficult challenge you face when allocating and deallocating in separate threads, it is not directly related to your question, so I'll leave that for another discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the response John.  I kept the question intentionally narrow as I'm aware that discussing the various potential pitfalls of writing multi-threaded code would take a large book.  I say this having fallen into many of said pits myself on more than one occasion ;)

Comment: It's like playing an old Activision game, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to allocate in one thread and free in another, you need the runtime library to be thread safe. The Microsoft runtimes have all been thread safe since Visual Studio 2005, Visuals Studio 2003 provides both single threaded and thread safe runtimes - obviously you should choose to link with the multithreaded ones if you're using threading.

As to whether it's legal, illegal or implementation dependent, I'd say none of the above. It's entirely outside the scope of the standard as it doesn't the mention threading at all.

Comment: Thanks Joe, well worth knowing since we still have some development sitting on VS2003.

Comment: VS2003 provides both multithreaded and single threaded runtimes - you just have to make sure you're linking against the right ones.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this unhelpful answer, but C++ Standard does not have threads, so all bets are off!

However, some C++ compilers and run-time systems support threading, on these you often have to tell the linker to use the thread safe version of the standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is implementation defined since C++ Standard doesn't say anything about how threads will share address space.

Answer (score 1):

it works because threads belong to the same process and share the same address space ..