# Dynamic variable declaration inside a thread

Tags: multithreading, dynamic-memory-allocation

As I got to know that apart from data segment and code segment threads also share heap segment

[What resources are shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762418/what-resources-are-shared-between-threads)?

then if I create a variable dynamically using malloc() or calloc() inside the thread then does that variable would be accessible to all the other threads of the same process?

Comment: HI ! Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before going on with your question. I would suggest you rephrase it as it is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you know the memory address. Yes, heap allocated variables should be accessible from any thread within the same process.

> > {malloc, calloc, realloc, free, posix_memalign} of glibc-2.2+ are thread safe
>
> http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.apps/2005-07/0323.html

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/is-malloc-thread-safe)

> Generally, malloc/new/free/delete on multi threaded systems are thread safe, so this should be no problem - and allocating in one thread , deallocating in another is a quite common thing to do.
>
> As threads are an implementation feature, it certainly is implementation dependant though - e.g. some systems require you to link with a multi threaded runtime library.

[And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363888/if-i-allocate-memory-in-one-thread-in-c-can-i-de-allocate-it-in-another)

Besides also answered in: [the link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762418/what-resources-are-shared-between-threads)

> Threads differ from traditional multitasking operating system
>   processes in that:
>
> - processes are typically independent, while threads exist as subsets of
>     a process processes carry considerable state information, whereas
> - multiple threads within a process share state as well as memory and
>     other resources processes have separate address spaces, whereas
> - threads share their address space processes interact only through
>     system-provided inter-process communication mechanisms. Context
> - switching between threads in the same process is typically faster than
>     context switching between processes.

So, yes it is.